# How post a model with a big list at .NET MVC (C#)?

Tags: c#, list, post

I am working on a form and I need to post a model and a list that is part of model. It is like a ticket and items, the model of the list has a lot of properties. So, If I post a model with 40 items and all theirs properties work, if I post 80 items still working, but... If I post like or above 80 items, the browser (Chrome) start to fail and sometimes collapse.

What could I do to post a big list?
Any idea?

The model looks like:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
        this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int TicketId{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items{get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId{get;set;}
    public int PropA{get;set;}
    public int PropB{get;set;}
    public int PropC{get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
    public int PropZ{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using bigger number like 1073741824 ?

Comment: If you are using POST, why are you setting the query string length? If you are not using POST, then that is the answer. URLs have a maximum cross browser limit of around 2000 characters, so you should not use GET with this much data.

Comment: I m using POST, you right,I dont need set the maxQueryStringLength and maxUrlLength. Any idea o best practices to POST a big list ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the maxQueryStringLength and maxUrlLength, it should not be an issue.(with your available targetFramework)

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" />
```

Should do the job.